# howcan I disable one of {{ }} commands in Laravel blade?

Tags: laravel-blade, amp-html

I create an AMP-HTML page using Laravel blade.

In sometimes, for AMP commands, I use `{{ }}` ... but Laravel, process it as a Laravel commands.

How can I disable only that **command** in that **line** in Laravel blade?

I know I can do it with include a pure PHP file in the PHP blade file. but can I do it directly in the blade file?

for example:

```
<amp-date-countdown timestamp-seconds="2147483648" layout="fixed-height" height="100">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
        {{d}} days, {{h}} hours, {{m}} minutes and {{s}} seconds until <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem">Y2K38</a>.
    </template>
</amp-date-countdown>
```

Comment: I had the same problem with a different templating engine that used the same ``{{`` ``}}`` as AMP. I found out that each engine has a `output raw` command. Not sure the correct one for Laravel, but output the brackets raw and it should work.

Comment: use `@{{ }}`  or `@verbatim {{ }} @endverbatim`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the AMP inside an [@php blade helper](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#raw-php)? In that way blade ignores everything within that tag.